# NextJS next-auth get session always null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, prisma, next-auth

Can't get the session data using getSession({req}) on a api call?
useSession() on a component is working fine.

package versions: nextjs@12.01, next-auth@4.3.1

issue: api/lists.ts:

```
import prisma from "../../../lib/prisma";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"
    
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  
     const session = await getSession({ req });
     console.log('session data is always null', session);
```

nexuauth.js config file:

```
callbacks: {
        session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {
            if (session?.user) {
                session.user.id = user.id;
            }
            // console.log('session callback', session);
            return session;
        },
    },
    session: { strategy: "database" },
```

_app.js file:

```
function MyApp({ Component, ...pageProps }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session} refetchInterval={5 * 60}>
      <Main>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Main>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

on a login.js file (working fine):

```
export default function Login() {

    const { data: session } = useSession()
```

Comment: Are you setting the cookies? Session depends on cookies, your browser automatically sends the cookies but `getSession` is server side so need to set those for a session to exist. https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/575

Comment: I'll move it to answer than. Glad it worked.

Comment: is there a way to set the cookies in request by default?

Comment: You can plug into interceptors, I have updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session depends on cookies, your browser automatically sends the cookies. So `useSession()`, which is on client side/browser always work. But when you use `getSession` **cookies are not present automatically**, we need to set them manually ([github issue](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/575))-

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    cookie: req.headers.cookie || "",
  },
});
```

To add these automatically you can perhaps plug into `interceptors` ([axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors), [fetch](https://blog.logrocket.com/intercepting-javascript-fetch-api-requests-responses/)) or make a `wrapper` function.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example#backend---api-route, you have to use [image: getServerSession]

In [...nextauth].ts, I `export const options`,
then use   `const session = await getServerSession(req, res, options)` in API instead of useSession will address this issue